# Is it possible to solve any given recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I am doing a sequences homework, and tried solving some given recurrence relations (even though it was not asked).
To my surprise, this proved really hard for some relations.
For example: $$u_{n+1}=u_n+2\ln(u_n)$$ or an even simpler one, $$u_{n+1}=au_n(1-u_n).$$
Is there a general theorem out there that can help me solve recurrence relations containing only elementary functions?

Comment: No.  In general, nonlinear recurrences like these have no closed form solution.  The secon one, $u_{n+1}=au_n(1-u_n)$ is called the **logistic map** and many research papers have been written about it.

Comment: As with most mathematical problems, it can only be decided whether the problem has solutions **within a given class of functions**. There are a number of algorithms for given types of recurrence equations.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such general result. You cannot get closed form solutions to recurrence relations (difference equations) any more than you can get closed form solutions to wide classes of differential equations.